# Is there a huge queue for Hergé Museum in Brussels?

Tags: tickets, museums, brussels

I'm planning to visit Hergé Museum in Brussels. I would like to know if I'm planning to buy tickets from the premises will there be huge queue on a Saturday?

Comment: https://www.ft.com/content/50387400-9362-11de-b146-00144feabdc0 "staff already report instances of 40-minute queues for admission at peak times" -- this was in 2009 so I am not posting as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have been there one month ago on a Saturday and I waited for 15 minutes. I arrived at 11:00 AM (ie in the morning). What I have found is that Bruxelles isn't so crowded right now.

Answer (score 2):

The Herge Museum is not in Brussels, it is in Louvain-La-Neuve, about an hour away by train. When I visited in 2012, there was little to no wait.